# In Django 1.8.2, how can I assign a "Task" model to a user account and let the user delete their own tasks?

Tags: django, authentication

I want to add a user account system to a website where the user simply adds tasks he or she needs to do, with the option to check mark each one and delete all existing checkmarks in their account.

So far, I was able to create a rough website where people could go in, add tasks, and modify them, with the help of jQuery and a few functions I've defined in my views module. I also made sure, with the help of a partner of mine, that I only do requests and responses for data only instead of the entire HTML page, as well as having my JavaScript run somewhat based on the backend where all of my tasks are saved.

I need to learn how the Django framework works.

A user can have multiple tasks in their checklist, so I must define a ForeignKey field in my ToDoChecklistTask model class. [According to Chapter 14 of the Django Book,](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html) though, I'm using Django's default user model from the django.contrib.auth module, so I don't know how to connect each ForeignKey to the user that is logged in currently to the site. I also don't know how to handle the request where the user wants to delete all the tasks that belong to him or her; so far, I only am telling Django to remove all the tasks from the server.

How can I connect each user to their individual tasks based on ForeignKey? And how can I access their tasks to delete them when the user sends the request to do so?

EDIT: I think a better question to ask is, what's the name of the class I must pass in the ForeignKey constructor that represents the individual user?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of points here.

If you need to extend the user model, use a [onetoone on User](https://github.com/brwr/thinkster-django-angular-tutorial-draft-1/blob/master/chapter02.md).

If you need to know the user behind the request, use [request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class myModel(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

This would let you do things like `request.user.task_set.all().delete()`

If you want to do all of this over AJAX, the world gets more complicated.  Permissions over REST APIs are, as I understand, a semi-unsolved problem.  See [this PyCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxP0lQCCiVo).

Comment: I'll try this out when I have a chance. By the way, when I render my template using one of three functions I defined in my views module, how can I retrieve a QuerySet of the tasks belonging to the user that's currently logged in? So far, I'm only asking it to get a QuerySet object holding all the ToDoChecklistTask objects from the database.

Comment: `request.user` in the view should give you access to that user variable, and you can traverse relationships (like your FK) from there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean I am to apply a filter and pass on the foreign key as the argument?

Comment: request.user should just be a model instance (like querying User.objects.all()[0] directly, but particular to the request's user) that you can call methods on like any other object in the ORM.